# Java 6/Clojure regular expression to capture content inside quotation marks, except for double-escaped quotes...and no StackOverflowErrors

Tags: java, regex, clojure

Let's say you've got a file of Clojure source code. The file itself might look like this:

```
(ns foo
  "We've got some sort of docstring here. \"this\" would be an example of
  some sort of escaped text within that docstring.")

(defn bar
  "Another docstring down here."
  [x]
  true)
```

Now, let's say, hypothetically, that I'd like to capture the contents of the one or both of the docstrings here.

The catch is that if I slurp this into a Clojure REPL, everything ends up double-escaped. So it looks like this:

```
(ns foo\n\"We've got some sort of docstring here. \\\"this\\\" would be an example of\nsome sort of escaped text within that docstring.\")\n\n(defn bar\n\"Another docstring down here.\"\n[x]\ntrue)
```

The regular expression I've been working with up until now is the following:

```
(re-find #"\"(\\.|[^\"])*\"" source-string)
```

This works reasonably well in that it passes all of the trivial test cases I can come up with. However, it doesn't take a particularly large corpus to cause it to run into a StackOverflowError.

And so, repository of great wizards, I turn to you. Should I be using a different regular expression? Are regexes *just the wrong answer* here? If so, what?

Comment: Try an unwrapped version: `"\"[^\"]*(?:\\.[^\"]*)*\""`.

Comment: What's the ultimate purpose of what you're doing?

Comment: @DaveNewton syntax highlighting.

Comment: In what environment? E.g., doesn't Clojure itself allow pulling out the docstrings?

Comment: I'm not just targeting docstrings. I want to be able to identify all proper strings in a file of Clojure source code.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to approach it as Clojure, instead of as a string of Clojure source code?

Comment: Ordinarily, yes. However, I have a few particular requirements here, and one of them is to examine the source code in question prior to macroexpansion. Think of the use case here as being very similar to that of an editor.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following based on `clojure.edn/read`:

```
(defn expr-seq [in]
  (let [r (.read in)]
    (if (= -1 r)
      nil
      (do
        (.unread in r)
        (cons (clojure.edn/read in) (lazy-seq (expr-seq in)))))))

(defn doc-string [[_ _ ds]]
  (when (string? ds) ds))

(def sexps
  (with-open [in (-> (slurp "/path/to/file.clj")
                     clojure.string/trim
                     java.io.StringReader.
                     java.io.PushbackReader.)]
    (doall (expr-seq in))))

; docstrings 
(map doc-string sexps)

=> ("We've got some sort of docstring here. \"this\" would be an example of\n  some sort of escaped text within that docstring." "Another docstring down here.")

; all strings
(filter string? (tree-seq coll? seq sexps))
```